# Problem with Picker in android (text of the selected item)

Tags: android, expo, react-native

I am having a problem with the picker (only in android). In the iPhone, I don't have any problem.
When I select an item, in android doesn’t update the text in the Combobox (but the object is selected ok).
I attach the code:

```
<View style={[Styles.PickerSelect, { width: “70%” }]}>

    <Picker
      headerBackButtonText="Atras"
      iosHeader="Seleccionar"
      selectedValue={this.state.articulo}
      placeholder={this.state.articulo}
      onValueChange={this.getDatosLineas.bind(this)>

            {this.state.articulos && this.state.articulos.map((item, i) => {
             return (
                    <Picker.Item
                         key={i}
                         value={i}
                         label={item.nom_articulo}/>
                     );
             })}
  </Picker>
</View>
```

I attach the photo of the example:
In 1- When I enter to the section, I have the picker with this text and value.
In 2- I select the picker, and I select another item (for example “ORUJO DE UVAS BLANCAS”)
In 3- In android, the text isn’t be updated. But the object is the selected…

[image]

I repeat, in ios, I don't have this problem.

Expo SDK: 36.0.0
Thanks!

Comment: You need to use setState() in onChange() of the picker.

Comment: Hi Karan, thank you. What do you mean with use the setstate() in onchange()? Can you send me an example or a link with this information?

Comment: You can share your code and i will add my line of code in that. @pituca_development

Comment: Yeah karan, i attach you

Comment: This is the code:

Comment: <View style={[Styles.PickerSelect, { width: “70%” }]}>

    <Picker
      headerBackButtonText="Atras"
      iosHeader="Seleccionar"
      selectedValue={this.state.articulo}
      placeholder={this.state.articulo}
      onValueChange={this.getDatosLineas.bind(this)>

            {this.state.articulos && this.state.articulos.map((item, i) => {
             return (
                    <Picker.Item
                         key={i}
                         value={i}
                         label={item.nom_articulo}/>
                     );
             })}
  </Picker>
</View>

Comment: @KaranMehta is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set selected value in **articulo** variable with **setState()** method in onValueChange() callback inside picker tag.

```
<View style={[Styles.PickerSelect, { width: “70%” }]}>

<Picker
  headerBackButtonText="Atras"
  iosHeader="Seleccionar"
  selectedValue={this.state.articulo}
  placeholder={this.state.articulo}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemPosition) =>  
                        this.setState({articulo: itemValue, choosenIndex: itemPosition})}>

        {this.state.articulos && this.state.articulos.map((item, i) => {
         return (
                <Picker.Item
                     key={i}
                     value={i}
                     label={item.nom_articulo}/>
                 );
         })}
```